# Convert data.frame with dates into xts time series

Tags: r, time-series, xts

I have the following data:

```
feb2007 <-
structure(list(V2 = structure(list(sec = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), min = 0:19, hour = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), mday = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), mon = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), year = c(107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 
107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 
107L), wday = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), yday = c(31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 
31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 
31L, 31L, 31L), isdst = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), zone = c("EST", 
"EST", "EST", "EST", "EST", "EST", "EST", "EST", "EST", "EST", 
"EST", "EST", "EST", "EST", "EST", "EST", "EST", "EST", "EST", 
"EST"), gmtoff = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_)), .Names = c("sec", "min", "hour", "mday", "mon",      
"year", "wday", "yday", "isdst", "zone", "gmtoff"), class = c("POSIXlt", 
"POSIXt")), V10 = c("45", "45", "45", "45", "45", "45", "44", 
"45", "45", "45", "45", "45", "45", "45", "45", "45", "45", "46", 
"46", "46"), V12 = c("43", "43", "43", "43", "43", "42", "42", 
"42", "43", "43", "43", "43", "43", "43", "43", "43", "43", "43", 
"43", "43")), .Names = c("V2", "V10", "V12"), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")

feb2007$V12 <- as.numeric(feb2007$V12)
feb2007$V10 <- as.numeric(feb2007$V10)
x <- xts(feb2007$V2,feb2007$V10)
```

But when I try to plot the time series, I get:

```
plot.xts(x)
# Error in as.POSIXlt.POSIXct(.POSIXct(.index(x)), tz = indexTZ(x)) : 
#   invalid 'tz' value
```

How can I fix this? I somehow believe that the POSIXlt class is not correct, but if I change it to as.Date then I lose hours and minutes which are essential for this problem.

Comment: Try `with(feb2007, xts(V10, order.by = V2))`.

Comment: Wow, thank you! I have one more question, I have 2 time series, one for 2006, one for 2007, if I use rbind (), can I stack them up without fear of loosing information????

Comment: Oh no @Pascal This gives me another problem. Please see the question.

Comment: What do you mean by "loosing information". By the way, the more simple is to try and if you are facing a problem, ask a new question with a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: True, I apologize. But now that I am plotting the time series I think there is an error somehow that I dont understand

Comment: Please provide a `dput(head(feb2007, 20))`.

Comment: `plot(x)` works fine for me.

Comment: It returns me > plot(x)
Error in as.POSIXlt.POSIXct(.POSIXct(.index(x)), tz = indexTZ(x)) : 
  invalid 'tz' value

Comment: Please start a clean session of R, load `xts` library and use your `dput()` to create `x`. Do you still have this error message?

Comment: Yes, I re-did everything. Same error. Is there any way of not using POSIXct ?

Comment: I didn't pay attention, but V10 is a character vector. It should be numeric.

Comment: I changed it....Suddenly all the times became NA. let me update the question

Comment: No, not the name, the content.

Comment: I added more information. I changed the column names and all the dates disappeared, so I changed it back and verified that the colums V10 V12 are numeric

Comment: As @Pascal said, please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) that illustrates your problem.  I've edited your question to make it reproducible, but I do not get the error you say you receive.